# How to bind multi-valued attributes in LDAP using Spring repository

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I want to retrieve a multi-valued attribute from LDAP using a Spring repository.

My actual code is something like this:

```
@Entry(objectClasses = { "class1", "class2" }, base="ou=my_base_dn")
public final class MyLdapEntity {

    @Id
    private Name dn;

    @Attribute(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Attribute(name="sureName")
    private String sureName;

    @Attribute(name="multiValuedAttr")
    private String[] multiValuedAttr;
}
```

And my repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface MyLdapRepository extends CrudRepository<MyLdapEntity, Long> {
}
```

And when I try to get the multivalued attr I can do it only with the first entry.

¿Is there any way to do this mapping with an annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

Instead of declaring the `multiValuedAttr` with `String[]` it must be defined as `List<String>`

```
@Entry(objectClasses = { "class1", "class2" }, base="ou=my_base_dn")
public final class MyLdapEntity {

    @Id
    private Name dn;

    @Attribute(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Attribute(name="sureName")
    private String sureName;

    @Attribute(name="multiValuedAttr")
    private String[] multiValuedAttr;
}
```

Maybe cause `List<String>` has methods to add elements without increment the array size explicitly.